# using RX JS for parsing a file upload on the browser

Tags: rxjs

I have a 500K line file on the client side that I need to use in my SPA as follows:

load file->parse it->validate each row->display the validation results
I am looking for a very fast way of doing this...

I was wondering is rxjs brings significats performance benefits here (other than its reactive style of programing) over other more standard ways of doing this
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

RxJS is a way of organising code, not a streaming/networking protocol. RxJS can be (and often is) used as an abstraction ontop of those.

If you have an opinionated RxJS wrapper around some API, it performs about as well as the native api. It's performance footprint is pretty small in that regard.